# Why we use "p1Index = -1" and "len=p1.parentNode.childNodes.length"?Please tell me wheater "p1.parentNode.childNodes" point to same thing?

Tags: javascript, web

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>DOM Range Example</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function useRanges() {
                var range1 = document.createRange(),
                    range2 = document.createRange(),
                    p1 = document.getElementById("p1"),                
                    p1Index = -1,
                    i, len;

                for (i=0, len=p1.parentNode.childNodes.length; i < len; i++) {
                    if (p1.parentNode.childNodes[i] == p1) {
                        p1Index = i;
                       break;
                    }
                }
```

'

> I find it in  the javascript for  web developer

here we can see p1Index = -1,why we don't use  p1Index=0 ?   '

Answer (score 0):

In your example p1Index is not referenced before it's reassigned as p1Index = i; so you could actually remove the assignment operator with no difference in the above example:

```
        function useRanges() {
            var range1 = document.createRange(),
                range2 = document.createRange(),
                p1 = document.getElementById("p1"),                
                p1Index, // The assignment isn't needed here
                i, len;

            for (i=0, len=p1.parentNode.childNodes.length; i < len; i++) {
                if (p1.parentNode.childNodes[i] == p1) {
                    p1Index = i; // It just gets overwritten here 
                    break;
                }
            }
            // It might be used down here somewhere - your code example wasn't complete - p1Index is only conditionally overwritten when p1.parentNode.childNodes[i] == p1
        }
```